# Matching 2 control matches for each case individual in r with matchit{MatchIt}

Tags: r

I'm trying to subset matched data with matchit function from MatchIt package in R.
I want to match 2 control matches for each case individual by AGE and SEX variables.
I've tried to use method="exact" and method="nearest", but I couldn't find the option to limit the number of control matches.
Does anyone have any idea how to solve it within the function?

Answer (score 4):

Hopefully you've solved it, but what you need is `method="nearest"` (if you want nearest neighbor matching), `exact=c("sex", "age"), ratio=2`. I strong recommend full matching though, using `method=full`.